# How do you conditionally hide values from your Angular template?

Tags: angularjs

How do you conditionally hide values from your Angular template?
I want to keep `payment.diff` blank instead of showing "€ 0.00".

```
<tr ng-repeat="payment in payments | filter:search.text | orderBy:sort:reverse"
    ng-hide="(search.minAmount != null && search.minAmount > payment.amount) || (search.tenantOnly && !payment.tenant)"
    ng-class="{danger: payment.diff > 0}">
    <td>{{payment.date | date : "dd&nbsp;MMM&nbsp;yyyy"}}</td>
    <td ng-attr-title="{{payment.tenant}}">{{payment.name}}</td>
    <td>{{payment.amount | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td>
    <td>{{payment.rent | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td>
    <td>{{payment.diff | filter : payment.diff != 0 | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td> <!-- How do I hide 0 values? -->
    <td>{{payment.desc}}</td>
    <td>{{payment.account}}</td>
</tr>
```

`filter : payment.diff != 0` doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add span tag as a container for contents and check like this <td><span ng-show="payment.diff != 0">{{payment.diff | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</span></td>

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<td ng-if="payment.diff != 0">{{payment.diff | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td>
<td ng-if="payment.diff == 0"></td>
```

Or

```
<td ng-show="payment.diff != 0">{{payment.diff | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td>
<td ng-hide="payment.diff != 0"></td>
```

The first one has the advantage of only running the filter when it's needed.

Comment: This hides the `td` I only want to keep the content blank.

Comment: Hide one td but shows the other with the blank content.

Comment: Ah sorry, needed both lines. Can it be done without the extra `td`?

Comment: You could overwrite the original currency filter but could be a problem in case you want to use it in other place in the application. I would go with the ng-if solution.

Comment: Went with combination of your answer and @Asik. `<td><span ng-if="payment.diff != 0">{{payment.diff | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</span></td>`